# How to create a scheduling task in office 365

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

In sharepoint online in office365, I need to create a Scheduling that reads document library at 6 a.m. which will check CustomDate field of document library and if its today's date it will execute some code.

How can i achieve this functionality??

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You could try to implement timer job functionality using [Microsoft Azure WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/) or Windows Task Scheduler to perform tasks in SharePoint Online . You could  run a console application which using the client-side object model (CSOM) as an Azure WebJob. Please click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn986826.aspx) for the basic concepts involved in deploying console applications as Azure WebJobs to run and access your SharePoint Online sites and content.

Comment: I would try the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint App, you can use Workflow to trigger event on list item update or created....